# Не выводится переменная, введенная в input. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Начал разбираться в Python.
Решил написать небольшой скриптик на запуск Wi-Fi с ноутбука.
 по идее я должен вводить эти строки в cmd вручную поочередно

- netsh wlan set hostednetwork allow netsh wlan set hostednetwork
- mode=allow ssid={name} key={password} keyUsage=persistent netsh wlan
- start hostednetwork

но я запилил небольшой скриптик.

```
import os
import time

cmd = 'netsh wlan set hostednetwork allow'
os.system(cmd)

time.sleep(2)

name = str(input("Введите имя Wi-Fi сети: "))
password = str(input("Введите пароль Wi-Fi сети: "))

time.sleep(2)
cmd = 'netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid={name} key={password} keyUsage=persistent'
os.system(cmd)

time.sleep(2)
cmd = 'netsh wlan start hostednetwork'
os.system(cmd)

print("Поздравляю!!! Wi-Fi Запущен!!!")

time.sleep(1)
cmd = 'netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security'
os.system(cmd)

input()
```

где imput настройка, что бы пользователь вводил имя сети и пароль при запуске.
но почему то переменная не встает. подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: `'netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid={name}` -> `f'netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid={name}`

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут явно была беда не с переменной.

```
import os
import time

os.system('netsh wlan set hostednetwork allow')

time.sleep(2)

name = str(input("Введите имя Wi-Fi сети: "))
password = str(input("Введите пароль Wi-Fi сети: "))

time.sleep(2)
os.system('netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=', name, ' key= ', password, ' keyUsage=persistent')

time.sleep(2)
os.system("netsh wlan start hostednetwork")

print("Поздравляю!!! Wi-Fi Запущен!!!")

time.sleep(1)
os.system('netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security')

input()
```

Пробуйте

Comment: Режим размещенной сети разрешен в службе беспроводной сети.

Введите имя Wi-Fi сети: Wi-Fi network Home
Введите пароль Wi-Fi сети: qwerty123456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\1\w2.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.system('netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=', name, ' key= ', password, ' keyUsage=persistent')
TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (5 given)

Comment: вариант выше с добавлением F помог...